# PHP cannot increase value in Postgres database

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I could use some help understanding an odd situation. I have a postgres database 'servers' with ip (inet) and load (integer) columns. I can manually update a load value via psql as follows:

```
UPDATE servers 
    SET load = load + 100 
WHERE ip = '10.10.10.10';
```

I have written a php script to automate load updates. However, the 'value = value + x' syntax is not working for me now.

THIS WORKS:

```
pg_query($conn, "UPDATE servers SET load = 100 WHERE ip = '10.10.10.10'");
```

THIS DOESN'T:

```
pg_query($conn, "UPDATE servers SET load = load + 100 WHERE ip = '10.10.10.10'");
```

When using the latter, the script hangs indefinitely without giving a response. I have tried variations such as adding an `or die(pg_last_error())` clause at the end. I have also tried using a `pg_prepare` and `pg_execute` statement. Still no output, and no change to the database.

Am I missing something? Is there an easy way to get around this (I'd rather not use a separate query to get load just so that I can add it back in).

Comment: Show your create table SQL.

Comment: If you connect to PostgreSQL in `psql` while it's hung and `select * from pg_stat_activity` do you see the query there? Is it `waiting=t`?

Comment: @DwayneTowell: Per work policy, I can't provide the details on the database. :/ As mentioned, the columns I am working with are an inet column and an integer column.

Comment: @CraigRinger: The query doesn't show up in pg_stat_activity.

Comment: Do you have an index on ip? and/or load?

Comment: There are no indexes on the table. I have solved the problem, though I am not sure how. I'll post an answer with details.

Comment: If it doesn't show up in `pg_stat_activity` it's probably a client side issue, where the client isn't figuring out that the query has finished, or it's a protocol issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. I am not certain why this was a problem, but it turns out that best practices helped solve it in the end anyway.

Instead of running a single pg_query, I set up appropriate variables and used pg_query_params. This is probably a good idea regardless of issues.

```
$myQuery = "UPDATE servers SET load = load + $1 WHERE ip = '$2'";
$serverIP = '10.10.10.10';
$loadAdded = '1234';
$result = pg_query_params($conn, $myQuery, array($loadAdded, $serverIP));
```

Again, I don't know why this solved the issue for me, but it did.